# AngularJS unable to update ng-repeat items failure in table "edit mode"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to implement a "edit mode" feature.

When edit button is clicked, function **backup** will back up the item.

When save button is clicked, function **save** will save it.

But it does not work for **Recover**

```
<a><i class="fa fa-lg" ng-click="item.editable? item.enable = !item.enable:''" ng-class="item.enable? 'fa-toggle-on text-success': 'fa-toggle-off text-danger'"></i></a>
<a ng-if="!item.editable"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-pencil-square text-primary" ng-click="backup(item)"></i></a>
<a ng-if="item.editable"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-check-square text-primary" ng-click="save(item)"></i></a>
<a ng-if="item.editable"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-reply text-danger" ng-click="recover(item)"></i></a>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ndw5W1Ukbdd9X0GvIZn5?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at my [Edited plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/g1dniIIKSw96hvuOL9LK?p=preview) .. I've added an `angular.extend(item, backup_item)` to properly update the item object with it's backup.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks man, this really saved my day. I will have to dig more into these angular APIs.

Comment: Glad to be helpful :)